# Add one value for whole result set

Tags: sql

I'm selecting rows from a table

```
select name,age from tabl1
```

I need to add another column which should have the same value for the whole result set.
the value is comming from:

```
select value from config where key = 'company'
```

How can I combine this into one query ?

The resultset should look like

```
Name1 | Age1 | SameComapanyName
Name2 | Age2 | SameComapanyName
Name3 | Age3 | SameComapanyName
Name4 | Age4 | SameComapanyName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
select t.name, t.age, c.value
from tabl1 t
cross join config c
where c.key = 'company'
```

**Added:**
It's maybe more appropriate when there is need to return more than one column at time from specific table.

There is a difference in behaviour between this and subquery as a column. When condition `c.key = 'company'` isn't met the join won't return records at all, in case on subquery it returns `null` value for each row.

**Added** (after @alex comment):

`cros join` returns `NxM` records that is true but not in this case. Here `where` condition limits `M` to specific row/-s only. Sometimes NxM result might be even requirement then subquery won't fulfil it.

Query (subquery version) fails when subquery returns more than one row or more than one column (that's why other answers limits returned rows in subquery to one by `top` or `max` which is not always sufficient). `cross join` will do it without any problems, it's is more elastic.

Tests done on tables:

```sql
create table species ( -- 9999 rows
    id int identity(1, 1), -- unique
    scientific varchar(50), -- not unique
    english varchar(50) -- unique
)

create table genus ( -- 2233 rows
    id int identity(1, 1), -- unique
    name varchar(50) -- unique
)
```

Before each query I've run:

```sql
dbcc freeproccache
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
```

Query:

```sql
select s.*, g.name
from species s
cross join genus g
where g.name = 'Pinaroloxias'
```

Execution plan:

[image: execution plan cross join]

Stats:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 5 ms.

(9999 row(s) affected)
Table 'species'. Scan count 1, logical reads 79, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 79, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'genus'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 11, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(4 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 46 ms,  elapsed time = 224 ms.
```

Query:

```sql
select s.*, (select g.name from genus g where g.name = 'Pinaroloxias')
from species s
```

Execution plan:

[image: execution plan subquery]

Stats:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 5 ms.

(9999 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'genus'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 11, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'species'. Scan count 1, logical reads 79, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 79, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(8 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 224 ms.
```

Query:

```sql
select s.*, (select max(g.name) from genus g where g.name = 'Pinaroloxias')
from species s
```

Execution plan:

[image: execution plan subquery with max]

Stats:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 31 ms.

(9999 row(s) affected)
Table 'species'. Scan count 1, logical reads 79, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 79, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'genus'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 11, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(6 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 229 ms.
```

The test would be better if I had done it many times and calculated the average but I had no time for that.

Comment: a cross join is a bit overkill for the job at hand

Comment: @alex, you are right it will do the job, but maybe it's more appropriate when there is need to return more than one column at time from specific table.

Comment: if tabl1 has N records and config has M records, cross join will return NxM records joining everything with everything, matching or not. This is a *huge* performance issue if the tables are large... definitely not something i would do in a production environment. EDIT: unless linq' cross join differs from SQL cross join, then I'll stand corrected.

Comment: @MichałPowaga interesting. looks like sql nowadays optimizes cross joins applying WHEREs *before* joining. good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery in the `SELECT` clause like so:

```
select name,age,(select max(value) from config where key = 'company') from tab1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
select name,age,(select top 1 value from config where key = 'company') from tab1
```

The top 1 is in the event that `config.key` is not guaranteed to be unique, to prevent the subquery from returning more than one row. (This assumed OP is using Sql Server)

Comment: because the OP expects a single value from the 'config' table. same result as MAX() or MIN() but no sorting involved.